# Ambari wont start

Tags: ambari

Hello why my ambari accessed from [datascienceworkbench](https://ambari.datascientistworkbench.com/) is just loading without finishing. Do I need to launch putty to access in ambari?
I've iused this [link](https://my.imdemocloud.com/projects/3467#!cluster) to acces in it.
[image: ambari page load infinitely]
[image: source]

Comment: Insufficient detail provided.

Comment: Hello, I’ve added image for details.

Comment: Sorry, those are not details.

Comment: Sorry I can’t be more detail as I’ve explained.  I lunch Ambari from the second image, and it shows the page in first image. With a loading at the upper left. It’s loading since yesterday!

Comment: You could give step-by-step details about how you set up this environment, so that we can tell you which step was done wrong.

Comment: It’s directly setup by IBM. I use it for online courses practice of ibm cognitiveclass. I’ve not touched to any settings of this one.

Comment: Then you probably need to ask IBM about this one!

Comment: If you don’t understand the problem why can’t let others try to help me?

Comment: They are certainly more than welcome to but I am trying to help you get your answer the best way possible and that is probably by contacting IBM. Sorry for giving you advice for free...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks you, I’ll contact them also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to run Ambari using Chrome? Also, looks like Adblock is active. Did you try to disable it?